# js in modal stops working after server validaiton fails ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an enterprise web application created using .NET Core 2.0, and I'm getting some rather unexpected results when a submitted form fails  validation. I'm creating a modal on a click event, which is populated with a form that resides in a partial view. The partial view references an external js file, and everything works as expected as long as the form is in an unsubmitted, or is in a valid state.

However, it gets strange when I submit invalid data via said form. The server side validation does it's job, and the error messages come back to the form as they are supposed to. The problem is that after the error messages are rendered, none of the other js used for the form works.

Now for the code. Here's the js that creates the modal and submits the form via site.js-

```
$(function () {
// stores the current URL in a variable to use for data update on modal. 
var placeholderElement = $('#modal-placeholder');

$('.trigger-ajax-modal[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.get(url).done(function (data) {
        placeholderElement.html(data);
        placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
    });
});

placeholderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
    var dataToSend = form.serialize();

    $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {
        var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
        placeholderElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);
        var isValid = newBody.length;
        if (isValid < 1) {
            placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Now for the js that stops after the validation errors are displayed-

```
$(document).ready(function () {    // <--works before form submission

//various code to do things like dynamically populate input via AJAX call based on a drop down list
// and doing simple arithmetic to avoid user error  

}); // <-- not so much after form is returned as invalid
```

The HttpPOST method in my controller-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MileageTrackerEditVM vm)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var dto = _mapper.Map<MileageTrackerDto>(vm);
        await _mileageTrackerSvc.UpdateMileageTracker(dto);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return PartialView("_Create", vm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("An general error has occured while trying to create a mileage entry: {0}", ex.Message);
    throw;
    }
}
```

and of course the validation scripts tag on the bottom of the partial view that's used for the modal-

```
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/MileageTrackers.js"></script>
```

Now for some of the variations I've tried-

- adding the `page.js` file to the `site.js` (where the js that runs modal creation lives) and then referencing `site.js` in the partial. Same result
- writing the js directly into the partial in  tags... same result
- adding the javascript to the razor `@section` Scripts bit, using `@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/ myJavaFile.js")`. Not only does this not work, but it won't even compile.
- Also, when debugging on the client side, as best as I can tell, the js file isn't being rendered with the validation messages.

I have searched high and low for a way to make that external js file render after form validation failure. I won't list every last permutation of the  phrase "js not working after form validation error" and other ways to describe my issue, but let's just leave it at a LOT. I am fresh out of ideas.

*DISCLAIMER-* I'm fairly new to programming (just over a year) so if any of my code is cringe-worthy, or this is a simple fix, I humbly apologize. Thanks in advance for any direction you may provide.

Comment: Can you show your submit method in `site.js`?

Comment: The $.post method is part of the function that calls the modal... I'll separate the two and see if that yields different results.

Comment: Oh didn't realize that. In the done function of `$.post` you replace the modal-body with the result of PartialView("_Create", vm). Can you look up what the server returns here? `.modal-body` needs to be the root element of this response.

Comment: For clarification... the response your asking about is the contents of 'data', and not the jQuery selector on the following line...
var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);  correct? I've isolated that data, and it's the entire HTML for the partial view. While the class modal-body is in that response it's not anywhere near the top. That's about 5 divs in.

Comment: This could be the problem as the scripts are probably in that html as well and cause issues. I suggest to try `placeholderElement.html(newBody);` in your post method.

Comment: You sir, are 100% correct. I implemented your suggestion, and now the js works after the form is returned as invalid. I appreciate the assistance. Since the was sussed out in the comments, would you like to put it in official answer form so I can mark it as the correct answer? You definitely deserve any rep points this gets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in my comment.
The problem is that the scripts are doubling up because they are not replaced properly.

The solution is to replace the root element of the `PartialView` Method.
I suggest to try `placeholderElement.html(newBody);` in your post method.